# drupal ajax message

Tags: ajax

Ok, i've been stuck on this for some time...

I have my own module where I alter the form to add my own button that returns a message from the server via AJAX. I'm stuck on the ajax part. When I click on the button, I see the url change to ../myforms/ajax But I get the same page returned as output instead of my ajax message

Here are my code snippets.

I click on the button that calls my getAjaxReply function:

```
function getAjaxReply(context, settings)
{
console.log("this works");
$url = this.href;
    jQuery.ajax
    (
        {
            type:'POST',
            url: '/myforms/ajax',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:voteSaved,
            data:'getAjaxReply=testingAjax',
        }
    )
    return false;
}
```

In my php file, I have

```
 
function myforms_menu()
{
    $items['myforms/ajax'] = array(
    'title' => t('myforms AJAX'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'myforms_ajaxCallback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
     );
```

```
 return $items;
```

}

//the php function
function myforms_ajaxCallback()
{
    if($_POST['getAjaxReply'] == 'testingAjax')
    {
        return drupal_json(
                array(
                    'answer' => 'success'
                    )
                );
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: How are you implementing myforms_ajaxCallback function?

Comment: OK updated the question with the myforms_ajaxCallback function

Comment: Just as an FYI, Drupal doesn't like camel case in PHP.

Comment: Have you cleared the menu cache?

Answer (score 1):

you also may consider using Drupal Ajax form API. This way you don't have to write any JS code or hook_menu entries. You basically alter your form to take user input into account. Just take a look at the examples:
http://drupal.org/node/752056

I recently ajaxified form by hand and after that reworked it to make use of api. And didn't regret ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do not `return` when calling drupal_json()

```
function myforms_ajaxCallback(){
    if($_POST['getAjaxReply'] == 'testingAjax'){
      drupal_json(array('answer' => 'success'));
    }else{
      drupal_json(array('answer' => 'failure'));
    }
}
```